# Create a map with same values and keys the FP way using ES6/Harmony

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-harmony

Given a set of "Apple", "Banana", and "Orange", create the following:

`{ "Apple": "Apple", "Banana": "Banana", "Orange": "Orange" }`

that is, each string becomes the key as well as the value.

(That is, by the way, what Facebook's little [KeyMirror](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/utils/keyMirror.js) JS utility does in their Flux examples.)

Is there a Functional Programming-style one-liner way of doing this using ES6/Harmony, e.g.:

`["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"].map(v => v: v)`

rather than a non-Functional Programming way of doing it, such as:

`let o = {}; for (let v of ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]) o[v] = v;`

Comment: fwiw, in Undescore/Lodash (with support down to ES3) — `var arr = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"]; _.object(arr, arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this, `.reduce((obj, str) => ({ ...obj, [str]: str }), {})`

for e.g :

```
var arry = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];
var map = arry.reduce((obj, str) => ({ ...obj, [str]: str }), {});
```

Comment: nice, thanks. :) There was me thinking that this wasn't possible yet. :)  But this is a good answer.  Looking forward to seeing performance metrics for this and for JS to have more FP methods like foldLeft/Right.

Comment: `['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'].reduce((m, v) => { m[v] = v; return m; }, {})); // using the arrow function`

Comment: Or using spread operator and returning object literal:

`['Apple', 'Banana', 'Orange'].reduce((obj, str) => ({ ...obj, [str]: str }), {})`

Terse but probably the worst performing option!